# not able to call a function within a simple jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm trying to call a function within a simple jquery plugin. I see that the init method adds 30 to the width but the add50 method throws error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'add50'`. Not sure what is causing this error to occur.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nsshrinivasan/KnDMq/6/

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    // Create the defaults once
    var pluginName = 'Extender',
        defaults = {
            propertyName: "value"
        };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init(this.element);
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {
        init : function (element) {
           // console.log($(this.element).width());
           $(element).width($(element).width() + 30);
        },
        add50 : function(element){
           $(element).width($(element).width() + 50);
        }

     };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
                new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    }

})( jQuery, window, document );

$('#metal').Extender().add50();
```

HTML:

```
<div id='metal'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#metal{
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: when you return `this` in `$.fn.plugin` it is the eleemts withing the selector, not the function itself. There are lots of resources regarding plugin authoring. For example in jQueryy docs main menu. Search in google also...lots of tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding something like this:

```
function Plugin( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;
    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    if (this[options]){
        this[options](this.element);
    } else {
        this.init(this.element);
    }
}
```

Then you can all your plugin like this: `$('#metal').Extender('add50');` and pass in your method as an option.
[jsFiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/psyon001/KnDMq/7/)

Comment: Awesome, this works too - could you elaborate what I was missing? it would help me understand my grey areas in constructing a basic plugin

Comment: I don't really write plugins this way - but all I did was add an if/else check to see if the option that was passed through matched any available methods. `this[options]` is the same as `this.add50` If any matches were found we invoke that method, else fallback to the normal init.

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KnDMq/8/)

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    // Create the defaults once
    var pluginName = 'Extender',
        defaults = {
            propertyName: "value"
        };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {
        init : function () {
           // console.log($(this.element).width());
           $(this.element).width($(this.element).width() + 30);
        },
        add50 : function(){
           $(this.element).width($(this.element).width() + 50);
        }

     };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
    }

})( jQuery, window, document );

$('#metal').Extender().add50();
```

Comment: Awesome, can you explain the change you made that caused this to work?

Comment: Returning the object instead of `this.each({});`